# What will be the derivative of energy w.r.t. mass?

Tags: special-relativity, differentiation, mass-energy

I am learning calculus, so while playing around with formulas I found a question.
What will be the derivative of the following function:
$E=(∆m)c²$?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{dE}{d(\Delta m)} = \frac{d}{d(\Delta m)} (\Delta m)c^2 = c^2.
$$
In this case $E$ is a first-order polynomial in $\Delta m$, so all that's left after differentiating is the constant that multiplies $\Delta m$.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I thought it would be 0 bcoz c is constant so that will become 0.

Comment: $c$ is a constant, but it doesn't disappear when you differentiate if it multiplies a function of $\Delta m$. One of the first things you learn when you start studying calculus is the [power rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_rule) - that's all I did. If you're still not convinced, have a go at differentiating $\Delta mc^2$ from [first principles](https://brilliant.org/wiki/derivative-by-first-principle).